# Why do we need this extra step in this proof?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

For some background information, given sets $I_1,\dots,I_n \subset A$ of a $C^{*}$ algebra $A$, we define $\prod_{k=1}^n I_k$ to be the closed linear span of all products of the form $\prod_{k=1}^n a_k$ for $a_k \in I_k$.

The claim is that given a $C^{*}$ algebra $A$ and closed ideals $I,J \subset A$, we have the equality $I \cap J = IJ$.  The proof is simple enough.

To show $IJ \subset I \cap J$ is obvious.  If $a \in IJ$, then $a=bc$ for $b \in I$ and $c \in J$.  Since $I,J$ are ideals, $bc \in I \cap J$, so $a \in I \cap J$.

To show $I \cap J \subset IJ$, it suffices to show that $(I \cap J)^{+} \subset IJ$, since $(I \cap J)^{+}$ linearly spans the $C^{*}$ algebra $I \cap J$ (closed ideals of a $C^{*}$ algebra are self adjoint.)

Let $a \in (I \cap J)^{+}$.  Then by definition, $a^{\frac{1}{2}} \in I \cap J$.  Since $I$ is a $C^{*}$ algebra itself there exists an approximate unit $(u_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \subset I$.  Hence: $$a = \lim_{\lambda} u_{\lambda}a = \lim_{\lambda} u_{\lambda}a^{1/2}a^{1/2} = \lim_{\lambda} (u_{\lambda}a^{1/2})a^{1/2}.$$ Since $u_{\lambda}a^{1/2} \in I$ for all $\lambda \in \Lambda$, and the net $(u_{\lambda}a^{1/2})_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ converges to $a^{1/2}$, it follows that $a \in IJ$.

My question is, why do we need to introduce an approximate unit into the mix?  Why can't we just say since $a^{1/2} \in I \cap J$, and $a=a^{1/2}a^{1/2}$, that $a^{1/2} \in I$ and $a^{1/2} \in J$, so $a^{1/2}a^{1/2}=a \in IJ$?

Comment: Why do we get $a^{1/2}\in I\cap J$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your approach, I see that you already know that closed ideals are $C^*$-algebras.

In that case, your proof is essentially correct and does not require the use of an approximate unit. Note however that when you say $a \in IJ$, then $a=bc$ for $b\in I$ and $c \in J$, you did make a tiny mistake. In general, such an element $a$ is a limit of sums of such products.

In reply to a comment above:

$a \in (I\cap J)^+$ means that $a$ is a positive element in the $C^*$-algebra $I \cap J$ , so it is certainly positive in both the ideals $I$ and $J$. Since $C^*$-algebras are closed under taking square roots of positive elements, we get $a^{1/2}\in I \cap J$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and pointing out my error!  We have that $a = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \gamma_k b_k c_k$ for $(\gamma_k) \subset \mathbb{C}$, $(b_k) \subset I$ and $(c_k) \subset J$.  Then using the fact that $I,J$ are ideals, $\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \gamma_k b_k c_k\right)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset I \cap J$, and since the series converges (to $a$), we invoke closedness of $I,J$ to conclude the limit $a \in I \cap J$.  This should fix my error, correct?

Comment: @Isochron A priory is not clear that you can write the element $a$ as such a sum, I think. But you do not need this.